# Laravel Target class [PagesController] does not exist error in Handler

Tags: php, laravel

My final goal is to use data from the database to display on the 404 page.

I have added the following code to my Handler.php in render method:

```
if ($this->isHttpException($exception)) {
    if ($exception->getStatusCode() == 404) {
        return response()->view('errors.' . '404', [], 404);
    }
}
```

Content of errors.404.blade.php is only "test".
I have checked the name of the PagesController file, and it is capitalized as it should. I've also tried to empty the cache with `Artisan::call('route:clear');`, `Artisan::call('cache:clear');`, `Artisan::call('cache:clear');`, and `Artisan::call('view:clear');` (I don't have access to the terminal directly).

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks.

Edit: This is the full handler file:

```
<?php

namespace App\Exceptions;

use Exception;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler as ExceptionHandler;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\App;

class Handler extends ExceptionHandler
{
    /**
     * A list of the exception types that are not reported.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $dontReport = [
        //
    ];

    /**
     * A list of the inputs that are never flashed for validation exceptions.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $dontFlash = [
        'password',
        'password_confirmation',
    ];

    /**
     * Report or log an exception.
     *
     * @param  \Exception  $exception
     * @return void
     *
     * @throws \Exception
     */
    public function report(Exception $exception)
    {
        parent::report($exception);
    }

    /**
     * Render an exception into an HTTP response.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Exception  $exception
     * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
     *
     * @throws \Exception
     */
    public function render($request, Exception $exception)
    {
        if ($this->isHttpException($exception)) {
            if ($exception->getStatusCode() == 404) {
                return response()->view('errors.' . '404', [], 404);
            }
        }
        return parent::render($request, $exception);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show your full error handler class?

Comment: I've updated the original question, thanks.

Comment: This could be a routing issue. Where are you referencing that `PagesController`? what (relative) URL are you hitting which causes that error?

Comment: Thanks for the help. Page content is loaded from the database. So if a user visits website.com/about the PagesController is called to get the content and some information for the header and footer, and then a view is called to display the page.

Answer (score 0):

**try this code**

```
if ($exception instanceof UnauthorizedException) {
    return response()->view('errors.403', [], 403);
}
return parent::render($request, $exception);
```

Comment: Why?  What does this code do that solves OP's problem?  OP was asking about 404s, your answer is about 403s ...? This might be the answer, but you would make it much higher quality if you *explain* what the problem is, and what your answer does to solve it.